# What does "Monthly on %1$s" mean when setting a recurring payment with Revolut app?

Tags: money-transfer, online-banking

When I try scheduling a recurring payment with my Revolut account,I can select a start date and then a "repeat" option, whose alternatives are:

- Never
- Daily
- Weekly on %1$s
- Monthly on %1$s

What does *on %1$s* mean for the last two?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/294327/what-does-the-token-1s-in-wordpress-represent/294330

Comment: @base64, so this means there's a little bug in the app, right?

Comment: %1$s is a placeholder for the first string argument. In other words it's probably an app bug.